# Check if file exists in step in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, jobs, exists

Need to create step in SQL job which check if file exist because if file exists it needed to be stop but if file not exist to continue with next step.
`xp_fileexist` not allowed in sql query.

Comment: if you use SQLServer Agent, can't you make an Operating System or Powershell command ?

Comment: yes, but on one way or another SQL agent will finish with success, I want to stop if file exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Powershell command on your job and raise an error if your file is not found so that your job will stop.
Something like:

```
if (-not (Test-Path $file)) 
{
    throw [System.IO.FileNotFoundException] "$file not found."
}
```

Comment: different logic. If file exists then stop